# How to export classes from the main application to libraries/plugins?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, visibility, dllexport

In a plugin-based application the core/executable has several pure virtual interface clases that plugins (dll/so) should implement. Further there are standard implementations of that interfaces, which should be accessible by the plugins.

Do I need to export pure virtual interfaces at all? I mean they consist only of header files which the libraries include anyway at compile time. So I should not need the symbol at runtime, should I?

How do I export classes from the main application to the plugins? Does this make sense at all? What is the best practice for this case?

This means that these symbols should be undefined in the libraries. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The pure virtual interfaces will include a virtual destructor that will lead the compiler to "creating" the v-table.

It is often a good idea to have this v-table created only in one compilation unit, and sometimes this is essential if you are going to use runtime type information on the class.

In a plug-in situation, you will potentially want to "verify" that the class implements your "interface" base class.

The main application can hook into the "model" that allows plugins to add some of its own, if you write it in a manner that allows these to be added in more than one way.

Comment: Indeed I need RTTI. Does this mean I should export the interfaces? Still I have no clue how to export them from the main applcation.

Comment: If you do it this way you'd put the interfaces into a library somewhere and get both your application and the plugins to include and link against them.
I am strongly tempted to point you to https://github.com/dotfield/ioc